# \mathcal gives different output where it should not

Tags: unicode-math, mathtools, mathcal

I have multiple occurences of `mathcal` in my document and they do not use the same style. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{STIX}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal},StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

$\operatorname{O}$
$\mathcal{S}$
$\text{$P$}$
$\mathcal{S}$

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE Output]

As you can see the two "S" charcters are different, which they should not be.

What have I done wrong?

Versions used:

- XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016)
- mathtools 2015/11/12 v1.18
- amsmath 2016/06/28 v2.15d
- unicode-math 2015/09/24 v0.8c

### Addendum

Loading `mathtools` after `unicode-math` solves this problem, but messes up other things. For example `\underbrace{X}_{0}` then gives:

[image: Underbrace output]

Comment: Looks okay in texlive 2017. I get the second S in both places. It works in texlive 2016 with `unicode-math 2017/01/27 v0.8d` too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I finally got around to updating my texlive and indeed now it works fine. Could you expand your comment into an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in `unicode-math`. See for example https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/356.

While it was fixed in 2017/01/27 v0.8d, it somehow reoccured later on and was finally fixed with https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/commit/0f245c2ec4c527397a67f3ff04aea8107a6cbe31 and released with 2018/02/01 v0.8l.